# File sharing across local network

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

After a little bit of research, I managed to get machine #1 to share two drives over my local net, apparently using samba.  All good so far.  Machine #1 is running Ubuntu 23.04.

Machine #2 is running Cinnamon Mint, and can *see* those shares.  When I try and mount them on machine #2 however, I get a 'Permission Denied' error.

Obvs, I've missed something important.  Can someone please point me in the right direction for ways to resolve this?  It would be nice to have access to my archives from both machines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user account you are using on Machine #2 has the correct permissions to access the Samba share on Machine #1. You can do this by logging in to Machine #1 as the user account that owns the Samba share and then running the following command:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <username>
```

Make sure that the Samba share is configured to allow guest access. You can do this by editing the smb.conf file on Machine #1 and adding the following line to the [global] section:

```
guest ok = yes
```

If both of the above fails try checking the folder permissions.Also in the smb.conf check the configurations. The following is an example.

```
[share]
path = /data
available = yes
valid users = system1_user
read only = no
```

Hope this helps